# MVC Login modal not logging in

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using an html form to post form data for logging in. I put it in a modal but it does absolutely nothing other than redirect to main page, and append the verification token, id and password to the url. Is there any reason why? It doesn't even enter the account controller

I just took the post request from the default Login class that comes with mvc projects and put it inside the modal.

AccountController.cs:

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("Login", model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Login.cshtml

```
@using Products.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/loginmodal.css">
</head>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive">
                <div id="logo-container"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <form action="" id="loginForm">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "E-mail", @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password", @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-def btn-block" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-center">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="#">Support</a>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts { 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have `<form action="" id="loginForm">` and `Html.BeginForm()` on the following line. The `Html.BeginForm()` renders another `<form>` element, nested in your case - which is not valid HTML. Browser probably takes the outer `<form>` where you specified `action=""`, that is why it is not entering your Account controller.

Answer (score 0):

remove this form

form action="" id="loginForm"

as you are creating 2 forms.

@using (Html.BeginForm  . . .) creates a form dynamically which will hit your actionresult.